# How to add the scissor operator in Quantum ESPRESSO input?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, electronic-structure, electronic-transport

I want to calculate the optical, transport and electronic properties of my material. GGA underestimate the bandgap.

I tried GGA+U but the bandgap is still underestimated and also when I tried to use it to calculate the restivity for example using EPW they say that DFT+U is not yet implemented.

So I was wondering how can I apply the scissor operator to GGA? Is it a good method?

Comment: See [this thread](https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/pipermail/users/2020-June/044832.html) about implementing scissor operator in QE. Also, not sure about EPW but in Yambo, they have [this tutorial](https://www.yambo-code.eu/wiki/index.php/Yambopy_tutorial:_band_structures) on how to calculate the band gap using scissors correction.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin Thank you. I was also wondering why EPW is not so much used to calculate resistivity?

Comment: sorry, I cannot help you. I do not have any idea about EPW.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but did you find an answer to this question yet? Otherwise, have you moved on from this part of your project?

Comment: @NikeDattani At the time I didn't find an answer, so I tried to improve my results a little bit by using more suitable values of U from the literature.

Answer (score 2):

[This comment by Abdul Muhaymin](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/how-to-add-the-scissor-operator-in-quantum-espresso-input#comment22621_10574) provides the following thread from the Quantum ESPRESSO mailing list which I'm including below (for me, I couldn't even visit the thread online because my browser told me that there was a security risk, so I clicked "accept risk and continue" but since I'm providing the contents here, you don't need to do that):

> > Is it possible to use the scissor operator in a TDDFT calculation
> > using turbo_davidson or turbo_lanczos?
>
> Yes in turbo_lanczos: the keyword is "scissor" in the lr_control
> namelist. But I do not remember if it is in Ry or eV.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Iurii

There was a follow-up question about whether the units are in Ry or eV:

> Dear Iurii, Thanks! It is not described in the docs, but I figured out
> that the variable scissor is used here:
> https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/TDDFPT/src/lr_apply_liouvillian.f90#L557:
> (and here:
> https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/TDDFPT/src/lr_apply_liouvillian.f90#L711
> )
>
> ```
>     DO ibnd = 1,nbnd       !       CALL zaxpy(ngk(1), CMPLX(-(et(ibnd,1)-scissor),0.0d0,DP), &                      &
> spsi1(:,ibnd), 1, sevc1_new(:,ibnd,1), 1)       !    ENDDO
> ```
>
> Can you tell from this bit whether it is in Ry or eV? It seems from
> lr_readin.f90 that the units aren't converted.
>
> Best wishes, Michal

The answer was given here:

> Dear Michal,
>
> Scissor must be specified in Ry units.
>
> Greetings,
>
> Iurii